# Docker - File remains after rebuild

Tags: docker

I had a clean Dockerfile:

```
from ubuntu:latest
workdir /home/
```

I updated my dockerfile to copy a file from the host to the container. 
Dockerfile:

```
copy config/.bashrc /home/
```

Built the image.

```
docker build --tag container .
```

I removed all the containers and images.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

I cleaned the system.

```
docker system prune --all --force --volumes
```

Then I rebuilt the image and checked inside of it...

```
docker build --tag container .
docker run -it container
```

The .bashrc still exists even after cleaning the system, removing it from the host, and removing any mention of it in the dockerfile.

I'm not sure why the .bash is still persisted to the container?

Comment: That `bashrc` file is the default file that is already present in ubuntu.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129144/165925.

Comment: The .bashrc has a comments and statements that are left in it from my copy.